Getting Error in shell script "unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''"
I wrote a simple shell script in /bin/sh and getting the issue below.
/tmp/a.sh: line 14: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/tmp/a.sh: line 17: syntax error: unexpected end of file

********** Shell Script *************
psqlCmd="DELETE FROM cmdb  WHERE cmdb.sys_class_path = '/!!/$['"


Always paste your script into https://shellcheck.net, a syntax checker, or install shellcheck locally. Make using shellcheck part of your development process.

And the usual reminder to always use single quotes when possible, switching to double quotes only when you actually need expansion.

Please include the entire script - it's evident the error is in line 14-17, and we need to see it if anyone should be able to help.

$[ ... ] is a deprecated bash syntax for arithmetic expansion. From man bash:

Arithmetic Expansion

   Arithmetic  expansion allows the evaluation of an arithmetic expression
   and the substitution of the result.  The format for  arithmetic  expan‐
   sion is:

          $((expression))

   The  old  format $[expression] is deprecated and will be removed in up‐
   coming versions of bash.


So for example
$ bash << 'EOF'
echo "'$[1+2]'"
EOF
'3'

but
$ bash << 'EOF'
echo "'$['"
EOF
bash: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
bash: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file

POSIX /bin/sh (which is provided by /bin/dash in Ubuntu) does not share this behavior:
$ sh << 'EOF'
echo "'$[1+2]'"
EOF
'$[1+2]'

$ sh << 'EOF'
echo "'$['"
EOF
'$['

So, although you mention "a simple shell script in /bin/sh" it seems you are actually running the script with bash. In either case, you can disable expansion by escaping the $:
psqlCmd="DELETE FROM cmdb  WHERE cmdb.sys_class_path = '/!!/\$['"

Note that in an interactive bash shell, you'd likely also have an issue with !! which is a shell history event designator - but history expansion is disabled by default in scripts.
See also:

How do I open the man page for square brackets math and what are they called?

bash: $[] vs. $(())


